# Is there a way to remove the 'time' portion from this chr string in my dataframe?

Tags: r

I am working with this dataframe in Jupyter notebooks: [Dataframe with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcpct.png)

As you can see the column is a chr datatype. I want to remove all instances of "12:00:00 AM" from this column. I have tried using the gsub function

```
bbData_sleepDay_clean <- gsub("12:00:00 AM", "", bbData_sleepDay_clean)
```

but it turns my data frame into this:
[Messed up output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB4nZ.png).

I know I can also convert this column into datetime, for which I tried this:

```
bbData_sleepDay_clean <- as.POSIXct(bbData_sleepDay_clean[[col2]], format="%Y/%/%d")
```

But I am not experienced with this conversion and it did not work.

Does anyone know a way to approach this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. See here for how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example  You can use `dput()` for your data. Instead of telling us it "did not work," show us what it did using the reproducible example - we should see error messages etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not appropriately referring to the column `date`.

In the first instance, if you want to use `gsub()` to simply replace the time part with "", then you can do this:

```
bbData_sleepDay_clean$date <- gsub(" 12:00:00 AM", "", bbData_sleepDay_clean$date)
```

In the second instance, you can use as.Date() directly like this:

```
bbData_sleepDay_clean$date <- as.Date(bbData_sleepDay_clean$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Output:

```
   id      date TotalMinutesAsleep TotalTimeInBed
1 p17 4/12/2016                415            818
2 p17 4/13/2016                463            118
3 p17 4/15/2016                179            299
4 p17 4/16/2016                526            229
5 p17 4/17/2016                195            244
6 p17 4/19/2016                938             14
```

Note that `date` column in the first instance will be class `character`, whereas in the second approach, date will be converted to clase `Date`

Input:

```
structure(list(id = c("p17", "p17", "p17", "p17", "p17", "p17"
), date = c("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM", 
"4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/16/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/17/2016 12:00:00 AM", 
"4/19/2016 12:00:00 AM"), TotalMinutesAsleep = c(415L, 463L, 
179L, 526L, 195L, 938L), TotalTimeInBed = c(818L, 118L, 299L, 
229L, 244L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Once I added '$date' it cleared up the problem!